# bash -vx and turn off the 'prompt_git'

Tags: bash, osx

I tried command `bash -vx`
which is stated that (By the way, these two options are particularly useful when you are testing or debugging a shell script.)

```
$ bash -vx
++ prompt_git ' on '
bash: prompt_git: command not found
```

After this command, `bash: prompt_git: command not found` is append to the output of every command:

```
$ uptime
uptime
+ uptime
 17:18:51  up   7:54,  2 users,  load average: 3.62, 4.03, 2.94
++ prompt_git ' on '
bash: prompt_git: command not found
```

How to set `prompt-git' off.

What's the reverse operation of `bash -vx`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What you *want* to do is get rid of the spurious error message, which you can very likely do by editing your ~/.bashrc and removing the `prompt_git` call.

Comment: I did not have it on the configuration `$ grep promot ~/.bash_profile
grep promot ~/.bash_profile
bash: prompt_git: command not found
`

Comment: @user10726006 He never mentioned `.bash_profile`.  Also, you spelled `prompt` wrong.

Comment: coz, I am working on MacOs @Kusalananda

Comment: @user10726006 I don't see what macOS has to do with it.